# rewrite condition not working after stripping query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iis-6, iirf

I am using iirf on IIS6 on a Windows 2003 server.  We have the following code to present clean urls and to remove any query strings:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\?(.+)&(.+)\.(htm)$  /$1    
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\?(.+)$       http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/$1 [R=301]

# Redirect to ASP if it exists.
# e.g. example.com/foo will display the contents of example.com/foo.asp

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asp -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.asp [L,QSA] 
RedirectRule ^/(.+)\.(asp)$       http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/$1 [R=301]

# Any bare URL will get rewritten to a URL with .htm appended
RewriteRule ^/([\w]+)$ /$1.htm [I,L]
RedirectRule ^/(.+)\.(htm)$       http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/$1 [R=301]
```

The problem is that since I have added 
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\?(.+)&(.+).(htm)$  /$1
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\?(.+)$       http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/$1 [R=301]

All query string parameters are removed where we actually need them for(sorry - urls not available externally):
betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/news.asp?page=2
In fact the only query string condition we want to to strip the parametrs for is if it contains the Facebook parameter fb_action_ids=52352315213 e.g.
betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/help?fb_action_ids=372043216205703&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582
I have tried using:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ fb_action_ids=(.)$ [I]
```

before the first pair of rules but but it does not appear to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just managed to resolve it and boy it feels like a burden off my shoulders:

```
#key thing I have changed is to specify the query string parameters fb_action_ids and fb_source
RewriteRule ^/(https?)://([^/]+)(/([^\?]+(\?(.*))?)?)?  /$1
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\?(fb_action_ids=(.*)|fb_source=(.*))$  http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/$1 [R=301]

# e.g. example.com/foo will display the contents of example.com/foo.asp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asp -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.asp [L,QSA] 
RedirectRule ^/(.+)\.(asp)$       http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/$1 [R=301]

# Any bare URL will get rewritten to a URL with .htm appended
RewriteRule ^/([\w]+)$ /$1.htm [I,L]
RedirectRule ^/(.+)\.(htm)$       http://betatest.bracknell-forest.gov.uk/$1 [R=301]
```